# Can objective-C or Objective C++ handle C++ exceptions?

Tags: c++, objective-c, exception, objective-c++

I have a C++ library for Network communication that I need to port for Mac, previously this library was used on Windows C++ app.

The flow of the C++ Network Lib is based on Exceptions in case of errors, instead of returning error code or last error..

Now since on Mac we use Objective-C/C++ for apps. I need to have UI in Objective-C/C++ but the lib used for the core network functionality is the same C++ lib.

So my question is will the objective C be able to handle exceptions thrown by C++ calls ? if so , how ? if not how do I resolve it ?
Or do we write a wrapper around C++ Lib calls and consume exceptions and return error codes ?

Please advise, how to solve it..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Provided you're using iOS or the 64-bit runtime on OS X, things pretty much just work.  You can write a C++ style try/catch and it will work as expected, as will @try/@catch.  Note that you'll still have the two distinct styles, for Objective-C and C++ exceptions; the only unification is the [special case](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Articles/Exceptions64Bit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009044-SW3) where a `catch(...)` or `@catch(...)` catches *all* exceptions, Objective-C or C++.  That's marginally useful for centralising your clean-up code, but about all you can then do with the exception itself is @throw it blindly again.

But in any case, [exceptions shouldn't be used for flow control in Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Articles/ExceptionsAndCocoaFrameworks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009045-SW1) (or Objective-C++) programs.  You should indeed endeavour to trap the C++ exceptions as they exit the library in question and convert them to a more appropriate mechanism, such as NSError.  In particular, avoid letting any of them raise through any Apple or 3rd party frameworks - most such frameworks are not exception safe for Objective-C exceptions, let alone C++ ones, and the consequences are thus undefined (mostly revolving around memory leaks, though many other failures are possible).

Comment: Good answer. Exceptions are a rarity in good Objective-C code and people tend to forget that when coming from other languages.

Comment: Can you explain how to catch throw codes from the C++ side ?