# Catching and printing info from exception from libc++abi.dylib: terminate... in Objective-C

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, exception, nslog

Is it possible to extract any information from the following:
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

I get this exception when i try to run some C++ parser on a string and wonder what the exception information is. Can i extract this info to a plain NSLog output in XCode?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910340/can-objective-c-or-objective-c-handle-c-exceptions Try this, seems there was the same issue and using `@try/@catch` does the trick/

Answer (score 0):

It seemed the error wasn't thrown by code, it had to do with wrong types being passes between functions. The error could be traced from Xcode debugger